# Any way to work-around "Choose Production" for puppet city bug

Tags: civilization-5

There is a bug, which is going to be fixed in the next patch, where you are blocking from going to the next turn with "Choose Production" for a puppet city. Clicking on the "Choose Production" does nothing, and the only way around it (that I've found) is to annex the city.

Does anyone know of a way to work-around the bug, while waiting for the patch?

Comment: FYI: It looks like this will be fixing in the [first major patch](http://forums.2kgames.com/forums/showthread.php?t=94438): `Fix for production prompt that sometimes appears with newly created puppet states that could stop the player from being able to end the turn.`

Comment: Hence the "which is going to be fixed in the next patch" in my question. Given that the ETA is next week it doesn't look like the work-around will be needed for very long.

Comment: *facepalm* Didn't see that, sorry....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this happen to me and I did not annex the city.  I just kept ending my turn using the shift enter keyboard shortcut.  After about 10 or 15 turns the game figured out that it was waiting on a puppet and "fixed" itself.

**Note:**  Be very careful you check all your cities before ending your turn.

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks!  The AI gave me like 14 cities at once in one game and I have to annex them all due to this bug.  Needless to say it did not do great things for my civ's happiness....

Comment: Also what works for me is to select "Research" or "Wealth" as the production. This is not possible all the time, but sometimes helps.

Comment: I couldn't even get the production selection dialog to open. Clicking did nothing, and clicking on the city just asked about annexing.